# Should application test be in application bundle

Tags: iphone

Should application test be included in application bundle when submitting to app store or it is for only testing purposes.

Comment: Are you referring to Unit Tests - if so, then the answer is no, you do not submit those to the appstore.

Comment: So then sentestingkit.framework can be removed from the project too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No and YES. Usually your tests reside in another target. For a given file you can tell it in which of those targets it should be. Your tests aren't of any use to an end user so I would not put them in your final application.

Comment: So then sentestingkit.framework can be removed from the project too.

Comment: Frameworks can also be assigned to targets (Check mark in the identity inspector)

Comment: how to remove apptest.octest from the product group. Delete is greyed out in edit menu.